# How to get XML type field's content of MSSQL Server 2012 in JAVA program

Tags: java, sql-server, xml, field

I have a table in MSSQL 2012 with one XML type field called 'XMLRECORD'. One record in the table has the below content in the XML field

```
           <row id="ARCUSER" xml:space="preserve">
             <c1>GENERIC USER FOR ARC IB</c1>
             <c2>ARCUSER01</c2>
             <c3>INT</c3>
             <c6>1</c4>
             <c8>GB0010001</c5>
             <c10>20130901M0601</c7>
             <c12>20130305</c8>
           </row>
```

I wrote a java code to read the above data completely including the xml tags. However when I execute

```
    ResultSet rs = s1.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM F_USER"); 
    rs.next();
    String res = rs.getSQLXML("XMLRECORD");
```

Then 'res' prints the output as GENERIC USER FOR ARC IBARCUSER01INT1GB001000120130901M060120130305

I could not see any of the xml tags.

Then if I change the code as below

```
    ResultSet rs = s1.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM F_USER"); 
    rs.next();
    java.sql.SQLXML xmlex = rs.getSQLXML(2);
    ex = xmlex.getString();
```

Even though the above is displaying the same result as GENERIC USER FOR ARC IBARCUSER01INT1GB001000120130901M060120130305

I would like to print the XMLRECORD field as it is including all the xml tags. Can any one help me on this please

Regards,
Manohar